# Select only first or last value for each unique value in data table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table like this.

```
> dt
    ID value
 1   a  v1
 2   a  v2
 3   a  v3
 4   a  v4
 5   a  v5
 6   b  v6
 7   b  v7
 8   b  v8
```

and I want to select only one **value** for each **ID**. It could be first value or last value. This is how I do it.

```
unique_id_value_mapping <- dt[, list(new_value=head(.SD[,value],1)), by="ID"]
```

But for large data tables(~0.1 million rows) it takes a lot of time. Anyone knows a faster way to do it?

**UPDATE**
The answer suggested for the above problem works fine.
But what if I need to pick value based on some condition. Consider a data table

```
> dt
    ID value days
 1   a  v1     2
 2   a  v2     4
 3   a  v3     7 *
 4   a  v4     7
 5   a  v5     1
 6   b  v6     5 *
 7   b  v7     4
 8   b  v8     2
```

and I want to select only one **value** for each **ID** wherever **days** is maximum for that **ID**. This is how I do it.

```
unique_id_value_mapping <- dt[, list(new_value=head(.SD[days==max(days),value])), by="ID"]
```

How to do it faster?

Comment: Why are you using `.SD`? That makes no sense. Why not just `dt[, .(new_value = head(value, 1)), ID]` or `dt[, .(new_value = tail(value, 1)), ID]`? Both `head` and `tail` are very efficient functions so you should get maximum speed of of this. Additional reason for decline in speed is if you have a big number of unique `ID`s which will make this basically a row operation (which is always slow).

Comment: @DavidArenburg On a 1e6 dataset, head, tail, timed  `0.014`

Comment: @akrun which is the same as your timings, no? `system.time` has some variance, so I guess it's within the threshold.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, it is similar.

Comment: Thanks guys. Solution works. I have updated the problem with more specification. Kindly suggest a solution for the update?

Comment: Maybe `dt[, .(new_value = value[which.max(days)]), ID]`

Comment: Check the top_n function in the package dplyr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
dt[, list(new_value=value[1L]), ID]
dt[, list(new_value= value[.N]), ID]
```

Using a bigger dataset

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(ID= sample(1:100, 1e6, replace=TRUE), 
     value=rnorm(1e6))
dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
system.time(dt1[, list(new_value=value[1L]), ID])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.012   0.000   0.013 
 system.time(dt1[, list(new_value=value[.N]), ID])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.011   0.000   0.012
```

#### Update

Based on the new update, as @David Arenburg suggested

```
 dt[, list(new_value = value[which.max(days)]), by = ID]
 #    ID new_value
 #1:  a        v3
 #2:  b        v6
```

Suppose you need the row that meets the condition

```
 dt[dt[, .I[which.max(days)], by = ID]$V1]
 #   ID value days
 #1:  a    v3    7
 #2:  b    v6    5
```

Or

```
 dt[, .SD[which.max(days)], by = ID]
```

Comment: But as you can see there are two rows for ID=a with max days=7 and I need to pick only first value(i.e. v3). I don't think it will do that. Should I use `dt[, list(new_value = head(value[which.max(days)],1)), by = ID]` ?

Comment: @shubham In your post, you mentioned that you wanted only one row per ID.  If there are ties, `dt[dt[, .I[day==max(days)], by=ID]$V1]`  Regarding picking the first value.  `which.max` returns the index of first maximum value and my code on the post does give you exactly what you asked.  I am not sure what you expect now.

Comment: Sorry. It's my mistake. Without trying I thought that it picks all the values wherever days==max(days) .